# Joomla! 4.1.5 category ACL logic

Tags: category, acl, joomla-4.1

I am struggling with the logic of an ACL setting in Joomla! 4.1.5. It concerns front-end editing, but I suspect it also applies to the back-end. It concerns the permissions of a category.

When I leave the "Create" permission, for the group under which a user logs in, at the default `Not Allowed (inherited)`, the category appears in the category select list on the article edit form nevertheless. The category can be set and the article saved, but after that it is no longer accessible/visible to that same user. This does not make sense. However, if I set the "Create" permission to `Denied`, the category does not appear in the select list and cannot be set.

Can someone explain this (il)logic? Am I missing something, or does it look like an imperfection in the ACL algorithm?

Comment: What the...? Is this "correction" really the level of nitpicking in this forum?